# Import Jupyter notebook as a module: path problems

Tags: python, module, path, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to load some of my Jupyter notebooks as modules. Jupyter has nice instructions on how to do it [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html). I have copied all the necessary functions and classes in the `notebook_import.py` ([full script on github](https://github.com/liartar/my_notebooks/blob/master/notebook_import.py)) and I load everything from it. Then I can import notebooks and it works:

```
# import functions and classes to make notebooks importable
from notebook_import import *
```

The following notebook contains test function `foo()` that prints `"bar"`

```
import notebook_import_test
[out]: importing Jupyter notebook from notebook_import_test.ipynb

notebook_import_test.foo()
[out]: bar
```

However, for some reason this only works if the notebook I am trying to import is in the same folder as the one to which I am importing. If I put the notebook in my usual folder for modules (i.e. the one where I put my `*.py` files with functions to load them later as modules), it says `No module named notebook_import_test`. I am not savvy enough with path management and how Python looks for modules to figure out how can I make this work for notebooks as for `*.py` imports, so that notebook load from another folder, dedicated to modules.

Any suggestions?

P.S. My OS is Win10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[I add this as an answer because as a comment the formatting is not enough to explain my comment. I'm guessing so maybe it is not a good answer].**

I suppose you are doing so from other notebook. If you started jupyter on a folder (you are on win10), e.g., inside folder:

```
C:\my_notebooks
```

And the notebook you want to import is on another folder not in the *C:\my_notebooks* folder, e.g., *C:\dir_with_the_nb_to_import*:

```
C:
├───my_notebooks       # Here you starter jupyter, > jupyter notebook
│   ├───notebooks      # so you have access to all the info in the folder
│   │   └───data
│   └───utils
├───dir_with_the_nb_to_import    # this folder is not inside my_notebooks
    └───notebook_to_import.ipynb # so maybe the problem is that it is not accesible
```

then jupyter doesn't allow you to find the file as you only have access to files included in the place you started your jupyter server.

I don't know if including *C:\dir_with_the_nb_to_import* to your `sys.path` would help in this case:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\dir_with_the_nb_to_import')
```

[EDIT]: After looking into your linked file it seems that changing [this line](https://github.com/liartar/my_notebooks/blob/master/notebook_import.py#L21) in the following way:

Before:

```
for d in path:
```

After:

```
for d in sys.path:
```

This way it will look for notebooks into the `sys.path` so you should add the place where the notebooks lie to your `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was useful to check, but this is not the case, unfortunately. I start my Jupyter in a folder above everything I use here, and both the folder with the notebook I am trying to import as well as the one to which I am importing, are in the sys.path.

Comment: Could you paste your *notebook_import.py* file somewhere in order to try to check if there is something wrong there?

Comment: Sure! I am adding the link to the question description. But it is just a copy of the functions from the Jupyter website. I suspect that find_notebook() is the function I need to tweak to make it work, but I haven't figured out how exactly to fix the problem...

Comment: Hi, today I found the time to look into your problem. I've updated the answer so let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks so much! I don't think I would have found this. I tried to understand how it sets the paths in which to look, but I was unable to understand what calls NotebookFinder.find_module(), that is the place where the path is set... anyway, thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Solution with 2 lines of code**

Use '**nbimporter**' package in python for importing another notebook A (or its function) in notebook B.  You can install 'nbimporter' by using the command - pip install nbimporter

Assume there are two Notebooks A.ipynb and B.ipynb. we are trying to import Notebook A (or its function) inside B  Code sample below should solve the issue.

**Inside Notebook B.ipynb**

```
import nbimporter
import A  # or do this --> from A import func1
```